Using jest.mocked to mock a selector factory
We have a selector factory like this:
const selectItems = state => state.items
const selectCategory = state => state.category
 
const makeSelectItemsByCategory = () => {
    const selectItemsByCategory = createSelector(
        [selectItems, selectCategory],
        (items, category) => items.filter(item => item.category === category)
    )
    return selectItemsByCategory
}

It is being used in a file that I am trying to test.
...
const itemsByCategory = makeSelectItemsByCategory()(getState())
// do stuff with this...

Now, in my test file, I am trying to mock the makeSelectItemsByCategory function and have typically done something like:
jest.mock('/path/to/selector/file', () => ({
    makeSelectItemsByCategory: jest.fn()
}))

describe('my-file-name', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { jest.resetAllMocks() })

    it('does stuff', () => {
         jest.mocked(makeSelectItemsByCategory).mockReturnValueOnce(() => []) // error here
         ....
    })
})

In other words, I want to mock that the return value of the makeSelectItemsByCategory is a function that returns an empty list.
However, I get a red squiggly line error on the argument to mockReturnValueOnce:

Argument of type '() => never[]' is not assignable to parameter of
type '((state: TReduxState) => any[]) & OutputSelectorFields<(args_0:
TMyType[]) => any[], { clearCache: () => void; }> & { ...; }'.
Type '() => never[]' is not assignable to type 'OutputSelectorFields<(args_0: TMyType[]) => any[], { clearCache: ()
=> void; }>'.ts(2345)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mock the selector is not recommended, you should create a mock store with different state and use the real selector implementation to calculate the derived data.
You can create a mock selector using createSelector and let the output selector returns an array.
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { makeSelectItemsByCategory } from './selector';

jest.mock('./selector', () => ({
  makeSelectItemsByCategory: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('my-file-name', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('does stuff', () => {
    const selectItemsByCategoryMock = createSelector(
      () => undefined,
      () => [1, 2, 3],
    );
    jest.mocked(makeSelectItemsByCategory).mockReturnValueOnce(selectItemsByCategoryMock);

    const itemsByCategory = makeSelectItemsByCategory()({});
    expect(itemsByCategory).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
  });
});


I took your advice and did not mock the selector but rather mocked the store instead. For my own learning, why is it not recommended to mock the selector? It is a function just like anything else so I figured that it'd be okay to mock that behavior.

@noblerare The selector function's implementation is not only just return a value but also memorize. If you mock it, you will break its real implementation. Your code maybe run, but the memorize of the selector is gone.
